# What am I doing wrong with scipy.signal.lfilter()?

Tags: python, filter, scipy

I want to test out simple IIR filter that I have determined myself on paper. I am filtering an audio signal that I can't provide here. I know what the ouput is supposed to be like and I am not getting what I was expecting. I guess the format of the coefficients is somewhat wrong, because the same approach works in MATLAB when using the filter() function.

```
import math
import cmath
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pi = np.pi

fs = 44100
offset = 1

data = np.zeros((10000,2))
for n in range(0,10000):
    data[n,0] = offset + np.sin(2*pi*3000*n/fs)
    data[n,1] = offset + np.cos(2*pi*3000*n/fs)
    if np.mod(n,70) == 0:
        offset = -offset

alpha = 0.4
b = np.array([alpha])
a = np.array([1, -(1-alpha)])

data2 = signal.lfilter(b, a, data)
data3 = data - data2

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
ax1.plot(data)
ax2.plot(data3)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data even if it's contrived?

Comment: I provided a minimal example and already found the problem. The issue seems to be that SciPy can' filter a three-dimensional array in one line. You have to filter each column separately. MATLAB can do this, so I was confused.